# IOS/xcode debug crash handling json feed

Tags: ios, debugging

IOS newb here having trouble with debugging.

Am trying to handle a json feed but code below is breaking at

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
         shnote = @"shnote”;
        lnote = @"lnote”;


        myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        self.title=@"Challenges";
        NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
        [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.~~/webservice.php"]];

          id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
         jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

         for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
//BREAKS HERE
         NSString *shnote_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"shnote”];
//ABOVE LINE HIGHLIGHTED IN GREEN AT BREAKPOINT
         NSString *lnote_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"lnote”];


         dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         shnote_data, shnote,lnote_data, lnote,nil];
         [myObject addObject:dictionary];
         }
    /*
         */
    }
```

The line highlighted in console is

```
dataDict = (NSDictionary *const)@"notes"
```

notes is name of table but other than that I am clueless.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is that a breakpoint ? If it is crash then is there any log in the console ?

Answer (score 1):

Your data source is of the format:

```
{
    "notes": [
        {
            "row": {
                "shnote": <...>,
                "lnote": <...>
            }
        },
        {
            "row": {
                "shnote": <...>,
                "lnote": <...>
            }
        },
        <...>
    ]
}
```

Steps to fetch each row content should therefore be:

1. Read value of `notes` property
2. Iterate through each `row`
3. Read value of `row` property
4. Read `shnote` and `lnote` properties

You're missing steps 1, 2 and 3. In code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.~~/webservice.php"];
NSData *jsonSource = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSDictionary *notes = jsonObject[@"notes"];
for(NSDictionary *note in notes) {
    NSDictionary *row = note[@"row"];
    NSString *shnote = row[@"shnote"];
    NSString *lnote = row[@"lnote"];

    NSLog(@"%@, %@", shnote, lnote);
}
```